# Perché si dice "marcio" nel modo di dire "avere torto marcio"? Si può usare "marcio" in modo analogo in altre espressioni?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, idioms, adjectives

In *Lo zio acquatico*, una "cosmicomica" di Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Eppure, il suo giudizio continuava ad avere un'autorità su tutti noi: finivamo per chiedergli consiglio su fatti di cui non capiva niente, benché sapessimo che poteva *avere torto marcio*.

Conoscevo l'espressione "avere torto", ma non "avere torto marcio". In Garzanti Linguistica ho trovato che l'aggettivo ["marcio"](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=marcio)

> si usa per rafforzare un concetto negativo: *sono sudato marcio*; *avere torto marcio*, completamente torto

e mi è sembrato davvero curioso. Sapreste dirmi qual è l'origine di questo uso del vocabolo "marcio"? Ci sono altri esempi di questo uso per rafforzare un concetto negativo diversi da quelli citati sopra ("sono sudato marcio", "avere torto marcio")?

Comment: Sono piuttosto d'accordo con Josh61, anche se credo che il punto chiave della sua risposta non sia stato esplicitato: provo a riscrivere quello che forse voleva dire, cioè che sicuramente è usato per rafforzare il significato di "essere sudato" e "avere torto" (da notare il fatto che di per se queste espressioni hanno un'accezione negativa, utilizzare "marcio" per rafforzare il significato di un'espressione che di per se ha un'accezione positiva suonerebbe veramente male) ma *probabilmente non ha un'etimologia particolare* (ritengo che Josh61 implicasse la parte in corsivo). [cont]

Comment: [cont] Anche in inglese nell'espressione "to be dead wrong" "dead" viene utilizzato per rafforzare il significato di "to be wrong", ma *suppongo* (come nel caso di sopra) che questo abbia poco a che vedere con un'etimologia specifica.

Comment: see something similar   in English, at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rottenly (The child is spoiled rotten.)

Answer (score 4):

Penso  che la connotazione negativa di un termine molto comune come 'marcio'  venga naturalmente usata per enfatizzare alcune espressioni.

> - [Avere torto marcio](http://www.newsinslowitalian.com/catalog/italian-expressions-proverbs/69/avere-torto-marcio.html) significa essere completamente in errore su qualcosa. L’aggettivo marcio si riferisce allo stato di decomposizione della materia organica, come la frutta, la verdura o il legno. Una mela marcia, ad esempio, è un oggetto repellente e non commestibile.
> - ***In senso figurato, marcio significa corrotto, moralmente guasto a livello individuale o collettivo***. Una società marcia è una società moralmente corrotta.
> - ***Spesso l’aggettivo marcio assume un ruolo enfatico, sottolineando un concetto negativo***: avere torto marcio. Se provassimo a sostituire la parola “marcio” con alcuni avverbi, come totalmente, completamente o assolutamente, il significato sarebbe lo stesso.
>     (www.newsinslowitalian.com)

- l'espressione 'torto marcio' sembra essere usata dagli inizi dell'Ottocento.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=torto%20marcio%2Cmarcio&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctorto%20marcio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmarcio%3B%2Cc0): *marcio vs torto marcio*

Comment: A me però non sembra tanto naturale questo uso di "marcio": non posso immaginare un uso simile nella mia lingua o in altre lingue romaniche che conosco.

Comment: Non capisco bene quale sia l'utilità di Ngram qui.

Comment: Forse sembra naturale a me che la sento e la uso da quando sono nato. Se la tua domanda è se 'marcio' avesse un altro significato in passato, lo escludo da quando risulta dall'etimologia e dai dizionari. Ngram fa vedere da quando si usa l'espressione 'torto marcio'. Non mi sembra che ad inizio ottocento avessi un accezione diversa, bensì penso sia un'estensione figurata del termine fatta da quel periodo.

Comment: No, non ho mai pensato che potesse avere un significato diverso in passato. Quello che a me sembra curioso è l'uso di quest'aggettivo in espressioni come "essere sudato marcio" o "avere torto marcio".

Comment: Hai ragione, e la tua domanda è interessante. Vediamo se ci sono altre ipotese in giro.

Comment: @Charo Penso che l'uso di "marcio" in "sudato marcio" e in "torto marcio" sia di tipo diverso. In "sudato" si riferisce al fatto che un liquido può far marcire se è in grande quantità (come in "legno marcio", cioè imbevuto d'umidità); nello stesso senso si usa anche dire "sudato fradicio" e "ubriaco fradicio", stesso concetto, imbevuto. In "torto marcio" è molto più indiretto e figurato; ma per me (madrelingua) è un uso comunissimo, anche se non mi vengono in mente altri usi altrettanto comuni di "marcio" per rafforzare un concetto negativo; ma ad es. "corrotto marcio" colloquialmente si dice.